# javascript nodegit unable to find remote

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodegit

Folks, I have a branch called `user/foo` that I'd like to check out from remote.  Code:

```
Git.prototype.refresh = function refresh(branch) {

    var options = {
        credentials: function() {
            return NodeGit.Cred.userpassPlaintextNew(GITHUB_TOKEN, "x-oauth-basic");
        },
        certificateCheck: function() {
            return 1;
        }
    };

    return NodeGit.Repository.open(localPath).then(function (repo) {

        return repo.checkoutBranch(branch, options).then(function (checkoutresult) {

            return repo.fetchAll(options).then(function (result) {
                return Promise.resolve(result);
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Unable to fetch',err);
                return Promise.reject(new Error(err));
            });
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log('checkoutBranch',err);
            return Promise.reject(new Error(err));
        });
    });
};
```

error:

```
[Error: Error: Reference 'refs/remotes/user/foo/HEAD' not found]
```

Am I using checkoutBranch incorrectly?  I already have the remote cloned to a local directory, and am trying to switch to a particular branch.

Thanks!

Comment: what resolution did u tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is copypasta from the [nodegit issue](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/523#issuecomment-88522121)

So you can only checkout a local branch. You're trying to checkout a remote. What you'll have to do is [get the commit on the remote branch](http://www.nodegit.org/api/repository/#getBranchCommit) and then use that to [create a new branch](http://www.nodegit.org/api/branch/#create) and then (optionally) [set the upstream](http://www.nodegit.org/api/branch/#setUpstream) to track the original remote branch.

At that point you can then check out your newly created local branch.